# How to hardcode value in QueryDSL Projections.bean return list

Tags: querydsl

```
query.from(user)
...    
.list(Projections.bean(User.class, user.id, user.commonName, user.selected));
```

How to hardcode user.selected to true or false in the above?

Note: I donot have `user.selected`in`where(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
query.from(user)
     .list(Projections.bean(User.class, user.id, user.commonName,
           BooleanTemplate.TRUE.as("selected")));
```

Comment: Timo, that did not work for me.. In `User` object - `selected` is a transient boolean property. So I had annotated it with `@QueryTransient`. And my projection is:  `Projections.bean(User.class, user.id, user.commonName, BooleanTemplate.TRUE.as(user.selected)`

Comment: @PondicherryFellow, shouldn't you have `("selected")`, rather than `(user.selected)`? Timo's example looks correct to me.

Comment: Robert, I tried selected first.. but that did not work. So only then tried user.selected. Also its not @QueryTransient, I had the property annotated as @QueryType(PropertyType.SIMPLE)

Comment: @Pondicherry what type is user.selected? Is it a `BooleanPath`? Perhaps it's stored as a `StringPath`, in which case use the `StringTemplate` class, rather than `BooleanTemplate`.

Comment: `@Transient
`private boolean selected;

Comment: Sorry @Pondicherry, not the definition in the bean, the definition in the path. It will be a `BooleanPath`, `StringPath` or similar. Go to the definition of the class for `user` in `query.from(user)`.